# Error while logging as root in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, authentication, terminal

When I try to change user to root, I get below error

```
➜  ~  su
Password: 
Cannot execute /usr/local/bin/fish: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how do I get rid of this? I do not have fish installed now. I had installed it earlier.

Comment: Run `su -s /bin/bash` and then `chsh` to change your shell

Comment: I tried. Get the below error.

Comment: ➜  ~  su -s /bin/bash
Password: 
Cannot execute /usr/local/bin/fish: No such file or directory
➜  ~

Comment: If you made your `.bashrc` or similar exec `/usr/local/bin/fish` then you can try `su -s /bin/dash` or something and fix your startup files

Comment: Change your shell to bash `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash`. I personally prefer `zsh`. Then execute your command.

Comment: I tried that . It does not work. There is nothing in my startup files which call fish

Comment: ➜  ~  sudo chsh -s /bin/bash
Password: 
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
➜  ~  echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
➜  ~

Comment: does not work . I tried this as well

Comment: for me the solution was to enter with `sudo bash` to enter as root ( using `su -s /bin/dash` did not work), then edit `/etc/passwd` and change every `/usr/local/bin/fish` to `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following and it worked for me.

1. Did "sudo bash" and got logged in as root. Was not able to login as root using normal "su" as it was throwing the error related to fish.
2. Deleted all traces of fish and zsh
3. logged out and logged in with my normal user name. Now , the default shell bash is working fine.